# IFTTT Applet not working

Tags: twitter, ifttt

I have created a If This Then That applet whiche reads as follows:

> If new feed item matches 'Lecturer:' from https://dedekindsarmy.github.io/feed.xml, then send a direct message to @dedekindsarmy

However, I published a trial post in my feed which includes in the description the `Lecturer:` substring and nothing happened.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you create the sample feed before creating the IFTTT Applet? What happens if you add a new item to your sample feed?

Comment: @silvamerica I created the feed before the IFTTT applet. Then I added a trial item to the feed after creating the Applet, which you can see [in the feed itself](https://dedekindsarmy.github.io/feed.xml). Nothing happened then.

Comment: @silvamerica I tried again for good measure - nothing happened.

Comment: @Jsevillamol it appears that the latest item in your feed dates back to Feb 10th, which is not considered recent enough. Please try adding a new event with a more recent published date

Comment: @davoclavo Yes that was it! Thank you!